# Error send image from client to WCF Server C# (Invalid length for a Base-64 char array)

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, base64

Hallo i have one wcf server and one client and i want to send/receive image from/to client as string  (convert to base64). I send from server to client already and works. I want to send from client to server and get error: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array. Probably the error is in xml file.

Here is my code:

***Server side:*** (WCFService.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
namespace Services
{
    public class WCFService : Services_Form, IWCFService
    {

        public string ImageToBase64(Image image)
        {
            using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
                byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                return base64String;

            }
        }

        public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
        {
            // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
            byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,
              imageBytes.Length);

            // Convert byte[] to Image
            ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
            return image;
        }

        //RECEIVE IMAGE
        public string getimage()
        {
            return ImageToBase64(pictureBox1.Image);
        }

        //SEND IMAGE
        public string postimage(string im)
        {
            pictureBox2.Image = Base64ToImage(im);
            return "Ok";
        }
    }
}
```

***(IWCFService.cs)***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace Services
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IWCFService
    {
        [OperationContract(Name = "image")]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            UriTemplate = "getimage")]
        string getimage();

        [OperationContract(Name = "image2")]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            UriTemplate = "postimage?Image={im}")]
        string postimage(string im);

    }
}
```

***The Server Form***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Services
{

    public partial class Services_Form : Form
    {
        ServiceHost host;
        string WCFPort;

        //SERVER FORM
        public Services_Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void StartWCFServer()
        {
                if (host == null)
                {
                    Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:"+WCFPort+"/");
                    host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCFService), baseAddress);
                    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWCFService), new WSHttpBinding(), "Services");
                    try
                    {
                        host.Open();

                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Change PORT");
                }
        }

        private void btn_StopServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (host != null)
            {
                host.Close();
            }
            else MessageBox.Show("Server already closed!");
        }

        //START SERVER BUTTON
        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WCFPort = "8000";
            StartWCFServer();    
        }
    }
}
```

**Server's App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>

      <service name="Services.WCFService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">

        <endpoint bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingDev" address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Services.IWCFService"  behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>

      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">

          <webHttp />

        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingDev">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"  maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

***Now the client side:***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
namespace Διαχείριση
{
    public partial class Administator_Form : Form
    {
        string IpAddress = "localhost";
        string Port = "8000";


        //CLIENT FORM
        public Administator_Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            try
            {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(UrlTag(""));
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();  
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error connect to server");
            }
        }

        public string ImageToBase64(Image image)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Convert Image to byte[]
                image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

                // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                return base64String;
            }
        }

        public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
        {
            // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
            byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,
              imageBytes.Length);

            // Convert byte[] to Image
            ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
            return image;
        }

        private T GetDataFromServer<T>(string url)
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(string.Format(url));
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
            DataContractJsonSerializer json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            T result = (T)json.ReadObject(stream);
            return result;

        }

        private string UrlTag(string tag)
        {
            return "http://" + IpAddress + ":" + Port + "/" + tag;
        }

        //SEND IMAGE
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string myParameters = "";
            myParameters = "?Image=" + ImageToBase64(pictureBox1.Image) + "";
            string responseMessage = GetDataFromServer<String>(UrlTag("postimage" + myParameters));
        }

        //RECEIVE IMAGE
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string img = GetDataFromServer<string>(UrlTag("getimage"));
            pictureBox2.Image = Base64ToImage(img);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your base64 string might have gotten polluted on the way there. Set a breakpoint and take a good look at it to see if it wasn't htmlencoded or urlencoded (telltale signs of urlencoded is spaces replaced by `+` symbols) etc

Comment: Sure that your second method has to be `GET`. I would expect `POST` (in second code fragement, `public interface IWCFService...`, the attributes of `postimage(string)`

Comment: have you try without wcf service ?

Comment: i dont try another way. The think is that Server can send image without any problem buy he cant receive. Xml config is ok?

Comment: Im sure that the problem is at url. Because when send server image he didt use link with base64 include in it. The client try to send the base64 from url. Here is the point. The base64 has invalid characters such as '+','-','=' .. The solution is to replace these character then send and then take it back.

Comment: This problem solved. Now i have another question. Must make new topic or can i ask here? Is for this project again. I want to event some data when fuction in WCFServices called. I want to create events to make changes in my Main Form with data of functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly i found a solution in my question. All the code is the same but in functions that i convert image to base64 and base64 to image i must replace **=** , **/** , **+** characters in base64 string with other characters because with these characters url was unavailable.

Here is the correct functions:

```
public string ImageToBase64(Image image)
    {
        using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
            byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            string a = base64String.Replace('/', '_').Replace('+', '-').Replace('=', ',');
            base64String = a;
            return base64String;
        }
    }

    public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
    {
        // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
        string a = base64String.Replace('_', '/').Replace('-', '+').Replace(',', '=');
        base64String = a;
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,
          imageBytes.Length);

        // Convert byte[] to Image
        ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        return image;
    }
```

With this way it works perfectly. If you have any other better ideas tell me to learn more thinks.